# Copying files content in C

Tags: c, linux, file

```
int copy( char *from, char *to )    {
    int fd_from, fd_to, rbytes, wbytes;
    char buff[256];
    if( ( fd_from = open( from, O_RDONLY ) ) == -1 )
        { perror( “open from” ); return( - 1 ); }
    if( ( fd_to = open( to, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0664 ) ) == -1 )
        { perror( “open to” ); return( -1 ); }
    if( ( rbytes = read( fd_from, buff, 256 ) ) == -1 )
         { perror( “read 1” ); return( -1 ); }
    while( rbytes > 0 )    {
        if( ( wbytes = write( fd_to, buff, rbytes ) ) == -1 )
            { perror( “write” ); return( -1 ); }
        if( wbytes != rbytes )
            { fprintf( stderr, “bad write\n” ); return( -1 ); }
        if( ( rbytes = read( fd_from, buff, 256 ) ) == -1 )
            { perror( “read 2” ); return( -1 ); }
    }
    close( fd_from ); close( fd_to );  return( 0 );
}
```

why is there a loop that checks if rbytes>0?

I understand the reasons for 2 if's statments inside the loop but not the last one, why do we have to read the file again?

Comment: Where did you get this code from? It appears to have been written in MS Word or some such... Can you post the actual code which compiles instead?

Comment: Incidentally this isn’t very good code; the `read` operation could be de-duplicated, and you’d normally avoid hard-coding the magic number 256 everywhere by using a constant, or by using `sizeof buff`. The formatting is also … *idiosyncratic*, to say the least.

Answer (score 2):

> why is there a loop that checks if rbytes>0?

Because every `read` operation only reads up to 256 bytes, yet most files are larger than that. The loop continues until the input file is fully read, at which point `read` will return 0, and the loop will terminate.

Comment: In assumption that we want to use this code just to read files below 256 bytes, then the loop won't be needed, right?

Comment: @LightLamps Yes, that’s correct.